# Android studio error: java version not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

In Android Studio I got the following error

```
Gradle snyc failed

Error:  no java version found.
```

I tried removing / renaming gradle but all in vain.
I am using linux mint cinnamon. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you installed java? Set JAVA_HOME?

Comment: yes i have .
when i execute java -version in terminal it gives following info
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

Comment: What about JAVA_HOME? Afaik, gradle needs that environment variable to find your jdk.

Comment: i have set it to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle .
is'nt it right ?

Comment: now have changed to /opt/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/jre/bin/java

Comment: To build java applications with gradle you need a java development kit so the correct path should be `export JAVA_HOME='/opt/jdk1.8.0_20/'`, if that is where your jdk is installed. So gradle can find `$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac`

Comment: but my jdk is not located in /opt

Comment: It was an example, based on your last comment. I'd suggest you find your jdk then ;)

Comment: my jdk path is /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Comment: thanks for all suggessions it's  resolved i had java 1.5 set for android studio i just changed to java 1.8 and its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to CMD and check whether Java is installed, just type `java` in cmd and press enter. If java is installed it will display options etc.

If you have installed java and its not displaying even when you type this command it means java path needs to be added to the Environment variables. to do this

> Select Start -> Computer -> System Properties -> Advanced system
> settings -> Environment Variables -> System variables -> PATH.
>
> Prepend C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.x.x.x\bin; to the beginning of the
> PATH variable.
>
> > **x.x.x is the version example jdk.6.0.27**
>
> Press OK to everything.